# Is there a tool to batch resize images to nearest power of two, on a specific side?

Tags: corona-sdk, gimp

For example, i have multiple images with similar properties like `width = 66` and `height = 62`, i would need the resulting image to be `64x60`, keeping its ratio. is there any Gimp plugin example, or a simple and fast to use tool that already does this?

My main problem is that the art department guys sometimes save hundreds of textures with the wrong resolution, for example, 1025x1025, which occupy 4 times as much memory as a 1024x1024 image, or or 560x520, which could be scaled down to not use too much memory. I know they should be the ones doing the resizing but at this point, but i would like to quickly correct the error for the sake of the whole team.

I am using Corona SDK, and using OSX Mavericks. A relevant document about image optimization on Corona can be found [here](http://docs.coronalabs.com/guide/basics/optimization/index.html). (Nothing we do not know about, basically power of two stuff.)

I have tried ImageMagick before, but right now i already started building my own gimp plugin thanks to the examples provided below, have done 1 gimp plugin before but this will be a new challenge.

Comment: Wouldn't it be better for editing and such to do it at runtime and only if necessary (pretty much all modern graphic cards should support non power of two textures)?

Comment: You should state which OS you are interested in. There are about half a dozen tools on Linux.

Comment: @Mario there are platforms that strictly enforce powers of two, for compression and rendering reasons. This is most noticeable on limited platforms such as hand helds and mobiles. Also, why waste run time cycles if you can do all of this as an asset pipeline step?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Gimp Script-Fu

You can batch resize images with Gimp thanks to **scripts**. You should probably look at some tutorials since it doesn't look very simple.

[Here](http://www.adp-gmbh.ch/misc/tools/script_fu/ex_09.html) is an example of batch resize, and [here](http://drbowman.over-blog.com/article-script-de-redimensionnement-sous-gimp-81743796.html) is an example that keeps aspect ratio. The intro is in french, it basically means:

> Here is an example of script that resize the current image to a 600 pixels width, keeping the same ratio. The function is inserted inside a menu *created for the occasion* called "mon_menu".
>
> To be able to work, the script has to be place inside the correct directory: `C:\Program Files\GIMP-2.0\share\gimp\2.0\scripts`. We will call it with a custom name like "custom_name.scm".

I can't provide a ready-made script.

Answer (score 1):

What I usually do when I need some very specific image manipulation (but also text, sound and pretty much anything), is to make a trivial throwaway program that does it for me.

It may sound really difficult, but it's not if you use a language and a library that lets you do stuff like that.

For example, in C# using `System.Drawing`, you can make a program that resizes an image to 64x64 (I know this is not exactly what you need. I just want to illustrate how simple it is to write a simple image manipulation program):

```
using System;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Drawing.Imaging;

static class Program
{
    [STAThread]
    static void Main()
    {
        var originalImage = (Bitmap)(Image.FromFile("original.png"));
        var convertedImage = new Bitmap(64, 64, PixelFormat.Format32bppArgb);
        using (Graphics g = Graphics.FromImage(convertedImage))
        {
            g.Clear(Color.Black);
            g.DrawImage(
                originalImage,
                new Rectangle(0, 0, 64, 64),
                new Rectangle(0, 0, originalImage.Width, originalImage.Height),
                GraphicsUnit.Pixel);
        }
        convertedImage.Save("converted.png");
    }
}
```

If you want to do it for all the images in a directory, you may want to look into `System.IO.Directory.EnumerateFiles()`. If you want to do it to the nearest power of two, you can change the way you determine the width and height, and so on.

With throwaway programs like these, you can do lots and lots of stuff.

Comment: Sounds good, but i don't know any tools to write C# on OSX, but i will keep it on mind, thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You could use imagemagick.

For a single image:

```
convert -resize 64x60! input.png
```

To convert all image you would:

```
mogrify -resize 64x60! *.png
```

http://www.imagemagick.org/script/mogrify.php

If you want it to calculate the size on the fly you do something like this:

http://www.imagemagick.org/discourse-server/viewtopic.php?f=1&t=11979#p39254

Comment: It is helpful, but the thing is, many of the images are totally  different, for example 1030 x 700, 257x256, 66x20 and so on. it's just that if it is a little bit over a power of two, lower it to that, but keeping the ratio.

Comment: @BasilioGerman I get you now.